# Is it possible to migrate Odoo 9 EE to Odoo 10 CE?

Tags: upgrade, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, migrate

I've odoo9 EE installed, I wanna migrate it to odoo 10 CE.
So, as developer, is there any tutorial may help me to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Being on Enterprise you should get free upgrade to the latest Odoo every year(in most cases). However, if you want to migrate to community and upgrade to 10.0 the flow would be:
- Uninstall enterprise modules so the Odoo has the same specs as community
- create a backup and install it on the Odoo 9CE
- migrate to version 10(for example using open-upgrade script)